# Is there a way to display a facebook group or wall photo album in a webpage using iframe

Tags: iframe, html

Have a domain and a facebook page.

Would like to display photo albums of the facebook page in a webpage on the site.

Would like new pictures and albums to display when added with no addition to code

Would like to be iframe.

I have searched through google and yahoo.  Also was looking at badges, but it want me to create a new page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. But if you use Wordpress or another blogging script/service, you can utilize a plugin such as [Facebook Walleria](http://zoxion.com/walleria/) to accomplish what you are trying to do.